# How to update HP Fortify 'Processing Rules' via REST

Tags: rest, fortify

I've read the documentation, and I get the REST API GET URL...

```
http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/6/resultProcessingRules
```

To work and return a list of the 'Profile - Processing Rules' for my application (via ID 6).
e.g.

```
"data": [
    {
      "displayName": "Require approval if the Build Project is different between scans",
      "identifier": "com.fortify.manager.BLL.processingrules.BuildProjectProcessingRule",
      "enabled": true,
      "displayable": true
    }
```

What I can't get to work is the PUT command to set this from 'enabled=true' to 'enabled=false'

I get back the same error message each time...

```
{
  "message": "An unexpected error occurred accessing resource of type Project Version Result Processing Rules.",
  "responseCode": 500,
  "errorCode": -20010
}
```

And the log just says...

```
2016-11-27 23:24:40,076   [ERROR] com.fortify.server.platform.endpoints.rest.ProjectVersionResultProcessingRulesController - ApiGeneralResourceException: &apos;An unexpected error occurred accessing resource of type Project Version Result Processing Rules.&apos; [url: &#x2F;ssc&#x2F;api&#x2F;v1&#x2F;projectVersions&#x2F;6&#x2F;resultProcessingRules]
2016-11-27 23:24:40,077   [WARN] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Can anyone tell me what the correct payload should be for this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Postman, I got this to work:

Here are the headers I used

- Authorization = FortifyToken A13D...E2
- Content-Type = application/json
- Accept = application/json

And here is the body:

```
[
  {
    "displayName": "Require approval if the Build Project is different between scans",
    "identifier": "com.fortify.manager.BLL.processingrules.BuildProjectProcessingRule",
    "enabled": true,
    "displayable": true
  }
]
```

**NOTE**

The trick I have used when trying to figure out who to call the REST API is to perform the action through the HTML5 UI while looking at the traffic (Fiddler, the browser's dev tools, etc).  Then looking at the requests that it sends.   The HTML5 interface uses the REST API under the hood.